# How to keep track of compiler environment

Tags: compiler-construction, f#

I don't have much experience with compilers, but I finally have to write one. I'm using FParsec for the parser and now working on the evaluator. I'm taking (*I think*) a pretty typical approach. I have an `eval` function that takes an environment and an AST node. The environment is a persistent type because it varies by scope. This requires `eval` and it's helpers to return `env * node` and all the environment passing is starting to get unwieldy.

What is the standard way of dealing with this? I'm starting to think having a shared environment that's mutated by each scope would be cleaner, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a state monad, as an alternative to using side-effects, in order to avoid most syntactic plumbing.

Comment: Do you think that would simplify things in a compiler?

Comment: I don't have enough experience trying it both ways to have a strong opinion.

Comment: I thought workflows have some syntactic limitations, but can't remember what they are.